# Как передать все параметры родителю

Tags: javascript, typescript

Есть такая функция в родителе

```
getUrl(key: string, format = {version: environment.api_version}): string
```

есть метод в котором она вызывается в наследнике, 
в этом же наследнике пишу 
getUrl(params){
  super.getUrl(params);
}

Как передать все параметры которые есть у родителя не перебирая их все по одному, может как то через трехточие

Comment: можете полный пример привести?

Comment: a `super.getUrl.apply(this, arguments)` не будет работать в TS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте Arguments object -
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments

Или передавайте параметры просто в объекте по типу ассоциативного массива.